# Why can't I pose my armature after setting a keyframe?

Tags: animation, dopesheet, pose-mode

I'm trying to use the Dope Sheet to animate a model I made, but after setting one keyframe (LocRot using the i key shortcut) any attempt to move any bone afterwards results in the bone being moved back to the position in the that one keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are editing the bone and adding the keyframes in Pose Mode.

1. Go to the starting frame.
2. Make the Location/Rotation change you want on the bone
3. Press the i key and select Loc/Rot

This establishes your starting position and rotation.

4. Go to the end frame.
5. Make the Location/Rotation change on the bone.
6. Press the i key and select Loc/Rot.

This establishes your end position and rotation

Your animation should play as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Spent hours on this, just found solution. It apears you can't change keyframe, you need to OVERRIDE it. Press "I" in Action Editor and new pose will be saved as a new keyframe.